# How can I run a cancellable task to update UI component

Tags: c#, winforms, task

Using c# .NET, I'm trying to update a label in a form and reset it to empty after a few seconds, if no other update is done (in that case, the reset must be cancelled and delayed again).

I've found different solutions with cancellable tasks and updating UI after a delay, but not both combined.

This is a try, that fails when updating properties out of the UI thread:

```
    private CancellationTokenSource TokenClearUIMessage;

    private void SetUIMessage(string Message, string Detail, Color Color)
    {
        if (TokenClearUIMessage != null) TokenClearUIMessage.Cancel();

        TokenClearUIMessage = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => {
            LblMessage.Text = "-"; // <= THROWS EXCEPTION
            LblMessage.BackColor = Color.White;
        }, TokenClearUIMessage.Token);

        LblMessage.Text = Message;
        LblMessage.BackColor = Color;
        LblDetails.Text = Detail;
    }
```

How can I proceed?
Thank you.

Edit: Recommended solution was useful ([How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread)) but not completed I still missed the cancellation option but leaded me to the right solution.

Comment: Please note that you want to take a [look at the 3rd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033198/1260204). The first 2 are still valid but considered dated.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, but it still misses the cancellation. I edited the question to include the right solution.